# Cannot split line and save to variable using whitespace in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, text, hash, split

I'm having some trouble with parsing a file.
Two lines in the file contain the word ' Mapped', and I would like to extract the number that is in those two lines.

[image: File looks like this:]

And this is my code:

```
my %cellHash    = ();
my $mapped      = 0;
my $alnPairs    = 0;
my @mappedReads = ();

while (<ALIGN_SUMMARY>) {
    chomp($_);

    if (/Mapped/) {
        print "\n$_\n";
        $mapped = (split / /, $_)[2];
        push(@mappedReads, $mapped);
    }

    if (/Aligned pairs/) {
        print "\n$_\n";
        $alnPairs = (split / /, $_)[4];
    }
}

{ $cellHash{$cellDir} } = (
    'MappedR1' => $mappedReads[0] ,
    'MappedR2' => $mappedReads[1] ,
    'AlnPairs' => $alnPairs ,
);

foreach my $cellName ( keys %cellHash){
    print OUTPUT $cellName,
        "\t", ${ $cellHash{$cellName} }{"LibSize"},
        "\t", ${ $cellHash{$cellName} }{"MappedR1"},
        "\t", ${ $cellHash{$cellName} }{"MappedR2"},
        "\t", ${ $cellHash{$cellName} }{"AlnPairs"},
        "\n";
}
```

But the OUTPUT file only has the 'AlignedPairs' column and never anything in MappedR1 or MappedR2.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the contents of your data file, not an image of your editor

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the file, it looks like there is more than a single space.  Here is an example of what I mean and what I did to extract the number.

```
my $test = "blah   :    123455";
my @test_ary = split(/ /, $test);
print scalar @test_ary . "\n";   # Prints the size of the array

$number = $1 if $test =~ m/([0-9]+)/;
print "$number\n";      # Prints the extracted number
```

Output of run:

```
Size of array: 8
The extracted number: 123455
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First off, paste in your actual input and output if you want anyone to actually test somethnig for you, not an image.
Second, you're not splitting on whitespace, you're splitting on a single literal space.  Use the special case of
 `split ' ', $_;`
to split on arbitrary length whitespace, discarding leading and trailing whitespace.